# Publishing Service in Azure Web App Won't Update Schema

Tags: paas, publishing-service

I am using `Sitecore 8.2 Update 7 Web Apps` and created an empty Web App. Following these instructions to deploy the Publishing Service, everything has worked except for the schema upgrade: http://www.ehabelgindy.com/run-sitecore-publishing-as-azure-cloud-service/

I am using the 64-bit version of Sitecore Publishing Service  2.2.1 rev. 180807-x64

```
Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema upgrade -f
[21:42:06 INF] Schema Upgrade
[21:42:13 ERR] There was an error querying Schema Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Common.Sql.Schema for azuresqlserver-sql.database.windows.net,1433\azure-master-db
[21:42:13 ERR] There was an error querying Schema Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Common.Sql.Schema for azuresqlserver-sql.database.windows.net,1433\azure-core-db
[21:42:13 ERR] There was an error querying Schema Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Common.Sql.Schema for azuresqlserver-web-sql.database.windows.net,1433\azure-web-db
[21:42:13 ERR] One or more errors occurred.
Command not found. Type help for a list of available commands.
```

Comment: I have tried following this blog post instead using 2.2.1 without any issues
https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-publishing-service-deploy-to-azure-with-arm-templates/

Comment: Great post. I just contacted Sitecore Support and they had me use the SQL Admin Account... which worked to update the schema. Unsure if I need to switch it back to the regular database contained user accounts (Azure SQL) or update the permission level for the user accounts.

Comment: It must be a user with full dbo access unfortunately. I'd just leave it, and ensure that there's adequate ip whitelist in place.

Comment: Support got back and said that for updating schema to use an account with full DBO but that it should work with the regular connectionStrings once the schema is updated by the DBO account

Comment: Did that work? If so, can you please add an answer with what you did to solve the issue?